# Issue with inline-block element when setting a width using CSS

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, css

I create an element and set the CSS display to inline-block. Then I measure its width with firebug and jquery .width() it returns the same and i think correct width of this element.

But then when I try to set the measured width using CSS the text inside inline-block elements breakes to another line. I just dont understand why.

This problem is related to Firefox and IE. Im using FF20 and IE9. You can try it yourself here http://jsfiddle.net/BMma2/1/

This is the code I used. Just uncomment the width in CSS and you will see.

```html
<p id="test">Some test string</p>
```

```css
p {
    padding: 3px 10px; 
    font-size: 28px; 
    height: 33px; 
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255); 
    background-color: rgb(88, 88, 88); 
    font-weight: bold; 
    display: inline-block; 
    /*width: 191px;*/
}
```

I have also tried to set the display to block but it wont help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that jQuery is lying to you.  It returns the width rounded to the nearest integer.  If the actual width is not an integer, the number returned by jQuery could be too large, or too small.  If it's too small, then setting the width to that number means the text won't fit.

Firefox and IE both do subpixel glyph positioning, so the length of a string of text will, in general, not be an integer number of pixels.

What you probably want to do is to use `getBoundingClienRect().width` to compute the width.  That will give you the actual width, without rounding.

Comment: no sorry that is also not so good. I have updated the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BMma2/4/ but the size the getBoundingClientRect() function is too wide. I think adding one pixel will be the only solution

Comment: @Sutulustus `getBoundingClientRect()` includes the padding and border.  You either want to use border-box sizing or subtract out the padding and border.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the display to inline fixes it, at least in FF.

Alternatively, adding another pixel or 2 of width should fix it - this would probably be more preferred, as in general, you should try to minimize the number of elements that have inline styling.

Comment: no sorry that is not the same. if you set the display to inline then width parameter does not apply on that element. also I could not just add pixel or 2. That is not a good solution